# How to switch between speakers in the Android client (Voximplant)

Tags: voximplant

I am developing a Voximplant application for Android and I can't find how to switch between speakers in the Android client, how do I switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via the IAudioDeviceManager method. Call the IAudioDeviceManager.selectAudioDevice() method with the following parameter: AudioDevice.SPEAKER.

https://voximplant.com/docs/references/androidsdk/hardware/iaudiodevicemanager#selectaudiodevice